# How to get total payments in php

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I have two  tables users and payments, in payments I have `user_id` `amount_to_pay` and `amount_paid`. 
I want to get users who didn't paid full payment, so

```
if($payments->amount_to_pay < $payments->amount_paid)
{ $unpayments += $amount_to_pay - $amount_paid}
```

But the problem is that a user has many payments so I need to check how many users didn't paid full subscription.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that these tables you are talking about are in a database?

I think probably the best way to do this check is through SQL

```
SELECT user_id, sum(amount_paid) AS paid  FROM payments GROUP BY user_id;
```

if you run that query you should get a list of all the users that have made payments and the total that they have paid so you can run over the results in a while or for loop easily.